# Calculate Internet Speed in Cordova App

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I know that we can determine whether the connection type is 2G,3G or wifi using `navigator.connection` in cordova.

But can we determine speed of the internet connection in cordova app.

Answer (score 0):

you can try downloading a sample file and calculate speed by `size/timetaken` formula.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. However it allows you  to access each device's network status and I guess you already know that.
Anyway you can check out the full documentation for further information, here is the link: 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html